# Reading the sub items of a Newtonsoft.Json.Linq jProperty using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I'm reading the following section of JSON from a url

https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=json&id=31542778,

```
        {
    "header": {
    "type": "esummary",
    "version": "0.3"
    },
    "result": {
    "28569071": {
    "uid": "28569071",
    "lastauthor": "Strayer SM",
    "articleids": [
    {
    "idtype": "pubmed",
    "idtypen": 1,
    "value": "28569071"
    },
    {
    "idtype": "doi",
    "idtypen": 3,
    "value": "10.1177/0890117117708841"
    }
    ],
    "references": []

},
```

I have some pretty nice code that I've picked up from stackoverflow and other places

```
Dim sublist As IEnumerable(Of Object)
Dim dic_list As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String)) = New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))

For Each item As JProperty In data
    item.CreateReader()
    Select Case item.Name
        Case "result" 'each record is inside the entries array
            For Each Entry As JProperty In item.Values
                Dim dic As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
                For Each Ent As JToken In Entry.Children
                    sublist = Ent.ToList()
                    If IsNumeric(sublist(0)) = False Then
                        For Each d As JProperty In sublist
                            If (d.Parent("articleids") IsNot Nothing) Then


                            End If

                            If (d.Parent("uid") IsNot Nothing) Then
                                dic("pmid") = d.Parent("uid").ToString
                            End If

                            If (d.Parent("pubdate") IsNot Nothing) Then
                                dic("pubdate") = d.Parent("pubdate").ToString
                            End If                                   
                    End If

                Next
                If dic.Count > 0 Then
                    dic_list.Add(dic)
                End If
            Next
    End Select
Next
```

But I need some help to build the ArticleID section. I've tried adding

```
    Dim itemObjects As JToken = d.Parent("articleids").Parent
    DList = itemObjects.ToList()
```

But that did not work.  I feel that I should make it into another list and then loop that but I can't seem to find the right combination of objects.  Your help is deeply appreciated.

Code I came up with that works since I can't answer my own question yet was

```
If (d.Parent("articleids") IsNot Nothing) Then
Dim articleids = New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))
For Each articleNode In d.Parent("articleids")
articleids.Add(New Dictionary(Of String, String))
If articleNode("idtype") IsNot Nothing Then
articleids.Last()("idtype") = articleNode("idtype").ToString()
End If
If articleNode("idtypen") IsNot Nothing Then
articleids.Last()("idtypen") = articleNode("idtypen").ToString()
End If
If articleNode("value") IsNot Nothing Then
articleids.Last()("value") = articleNode("value").ToString()
End If
Next articleNode
dic("articleids") = articleids
End if
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Just deserialize the JSON? To a nested Dictionary? Is there a specific reason?

Comment: I'm pulling data from 5 different web api and combining them into one result set.  Some I attach to come back as XML some as JSON.  All of this is being done on the fly with no database on my end to support it.  So first there is a search and then that returning result is sent to another api and I take 4 elements from here and 5 from there and send one element to another api for processing and taking the returning result set and combining that.

Comment: The bottom line is that I'm doing some data gathering and analysis from various sources on 100's of initial request.  I have found the putting what I need into a dictionary so I can match up to the ID's from another API call seems to be fairly efficient.  If you have a better idea- I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: There's none of this in the question you have posted. If that's the goal, what's in the question doesn't explain in any way what you need help with. Also not clear (from the comments) what you're gathering and from where (different sources? Different JSON structures) and what the final result should look like (given some samples of the data).

Comment: Thanks for the help- but all I wanted help for is how to read the sub items of the articleids- I figured it out and maybe I should just deleted the entire question

Comment: You could simply deserialize the JSON(s) to (a) class object(s) and build an expandable class container that receives the data from different sources, if necessary, with *custom logic* (whatever that is, you didn't say). To index these objects using a Dictionary is trivial.